# How do I implement the WS addressing using WCF?

Tags: wcf, ws-addressing

How do I implement the WS addressing using WCF?

Answer (score 1):

WCF automatically inserts appropriate WS-Addressing headers into messages created with the wsHttpBinding, and probably with some other bindings too.

Did you mean that you want to exert some control over those headers?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following instruction in your binding

```
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"/>
```